# Do I need to root my Pixel 3 phone in order to install GrapheneOS?

Tags: rooting, rom-flashing, bootloader

I am interested in stalling [GrapheneOS](https://grapheneos.org/) custom ROM on a Pixel 3 phone.

Does this require that I root the phone?

Answer (score 1):

No, it is neither required, nor recommended to root the device.

You will need to follow the official instructions here: https://grapheneos.org/install

It will require you to:

1. Upgrade the stock OS (to get any firmware updates)
2. Show dev options.
3. Enable OEM unlocking.
4. Actually unlock the bootloader.
5. Install GrapheneOS via `fastboot`
6. Lock the bootloader.